# How to create a component like KeepAlive in vue3.x

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

#### Version

3.1.2

#### Reproduction link

https://github.com/hezhongfeng/vue-page-stack/tree/next

#### Steps to reproduce

I don't like Vue's KeepAlive  cache policy , So I want to create a component like KeepAlive.
But When I use my Component  with `transition`，there is a error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of null`.
This error is create by `packages/runtime-core/src/componentSlots.ts` initSlots.
I don't know how to resolve it.

```
const KKeepAliveImpl: ComponentOptions = {
  name: `KKeepAlive`,
  __isKeepAlive: true,

  setup(props, { slots }: SetupContext) {
    return () => {};
  },
};

const KKeepAlive = KKeepAliveImpl as any as {
  __isKeepAlive: true;
  new (): {
    $props: VNodeProps;
  };
};
```

Anyone has a idea?

Comment: I don't know if it answers your question correctly, but you could use `v-show` to keep the component alive.

Comment: @wittgenstein thank you for your answer.Actually, I want to custom a KeepAlive. like this https://github.com/hezhongfeng/vue-page-stack/tree/next  And there is a PR https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/3414